# Separated Spaces and a Partition Differences?

Tags: general-topology

I am just getting a handle on separated definitions from Topology , reading Munkres.

So the definition of a separated subsets of a  topology, is that they are both disjoint.  Further, if each subset is disjoint from the other's closure, then this is also separated , which yields disjointedness.

(separated subsets must be non empty)

my question, is what is the difference between separated subsets, and a partition?  a partition requires that the union must equal the parent set (same with separate subsets) , and that each must be disjoint (same with separated subsets).

However, with separated subsets, we can separate them by the closure definition.  we can separate subsets by finding disjoint neighborhoods which are open.   You can show that sets are separate by finding disjoint closed neighborhoods,  and you can find separateness by function.

I just wish to have some clarity with the difference with a partition and separation. thank you very much.

Comment: $\{\Bbb Q,\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q\}$ is a partition of $\Bbb R$, but the sets $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ are very far from being separated: each has all of $\Bbb R$ as its closure.

Comment: so if sets are disjoint, that is not strong enough assertion? the example shows that if sets are disjoint, then that does not guarantee separate, but separate guarantees disjoint.  is this it?

Comment: To make them separated? No, not at all. In order for $A$ and $B$ to be separated, you need to have $A\cap\operatorname{cl}B=B\cap\operatorname{cl}A=\varnothing$. That’s a much stronger requirement.

Comment: this example then stumps me.  it clearly satisfies the disjointed-ness property, but wiggles out of separateness.

Comment: I’m not sure what’s confusing about it: it’s simply one of many examples of disjoint sets that aren’t separated. (And since $\Bbb R$ is connected, you won’t be able to write it as the union of two separated sets.)

Comment: I see, the definition includes that each set must also be disjoint from the each other's closure, there is extra condition.  i see. thank you.

Comment: Now you’ve got it; you’re welcome.

Comment: Put another way, disjointedness just depends on the sets involved (and not the topology) but separation depends on the topology.